# Why Elasticsearch "not_analyzed" field is split into terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following field in my mapping definition:

```
...
"my_field": {
  "type": "string",
  "index":"not_analyzed"
}
...
```

When I index a document with value of `my_field = 'test-some-another'` that value is split into 3 terms: `test`, `some`, `another`.

What am I doing wrong?

I created the following index:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index -d '{
   "index": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_source": {
          "compressed": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "my_field": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then I index the following document:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/my_index/my_type -d '{
  "my_field": "test-some-another"
}'
```

Then I use the plugin https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist with the following API:

    `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_termlist`

That gives me the following response:

```
{"ok":true,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"terms": ["test","some","another"]}
```

Comment: Can you add a more detailed example that demonstrates the problem? How did you determine that test-some-another is indeed split into 3 terms?

Comment: I modified my question in order to answer yours. Thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Verify that mapping is actually getting set by running:

`curl localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty=true`

The command that creates the index seems to be incorrect. It shouldn't contain `"index" : {` as a root element. Try this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index -d '{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_source": {
        "compressed": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thank you! My mapping definition is applied now.

Answer (score 4):

In ElasticSearch a field is indexed when it goes within the inverted index, the data structure that lucene uses to provide its great and fast full text search capabilities. If you want to search on a field, you do have to index it. When you index a field you can decide whether you want to index it as it is, or you want to analyze it, which means deciding a tokenizer to apply to it, which will generate a list of tokens (words) and a list of token filters that can modify the generated tokens (even add or delete some). The way you index a field affects how you can search on it. If you index a field but don't analyze it, and its text is composed of multiple words, you'll be able to find that document only searching for that exact specific text, whitespaces included.

You can have fields that you only want to search on, and never show: indexed and not stored (default in lucene).
You can have fields that you want to search on and also retrieve: indexed and stored.
You can have fields that you don't want to search on, but you do want to retrieve to show them.