# Elasticsearch sorting on string not returning expected results

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

When sorting on a string field with multiple words, Elasticsearch is splitting the string value and using the min or max as the sort value. I.E.: when sorting on a field with the value "Eye of the Tiger" in ascending order, the sort value is: "Eye" and when sorting in descending order the value is: "Tiger".

Lets say I have "Eye of the Tiger" and "Wheel of Death" as entries in my index, when I do an ascending sort on this field, I would expect, "Eye of the Tiger" to be first, since "E" comes before "W", but what I'm seeing when sorting on this field, "Wheel of Death" is coming up first, since "D" is the min value of that term and "E" is the min value of "Eye of the Tiger".

Does anyone know how to turn off this behavior and just allow a regular sort on this string field?

Comment: how is that field mapped? Sounds like it is tokenized into pieces, not analyzed as a whole string. You might need ```"index": "not_analyzed"```

Comment: The field is mapped as a string. So I would basically need to do that for every field that I wanted to sort on that contained multiple terms? I was doing some more digging and came across this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583013/why-elasticsearch-not-analyzed-field-is-split-into-terms which sounds similar to what your suggesting. Is this the only way in Elasticsearch? it just feels pretty clunky

Comment: Here is a helpful blog post related to the topic http://awesomism.co.uk/sorting-string-fields-with-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mconlin mentioned if you want to sort on the unanalyzed doc field you need to specify "index": "not_analyzed" to sort as you described. But if you're looking to be able to keep this field tokenized to search on, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384894/elasticsearch-return-the-complete-value-of-a-facet-for-a-query) by sloan shows a great example. Using [multi-field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html) to keep two different mappings for a field is very common in Elasticsearch.

Hope this helps, let me know if I can offer more explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the sorting to be case-insensitive `"index": "not_analyzed"` doesn't work, so I've created a custom sort analyzer.

index-settings.yml

```
index :   
    analysis :
        analyzer :
            sort :
                type : custom
                tokenizer : keyword
                filter : [lowercase]
```

Mapping:

```
...
"articleName": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "standard",
    "fields": {
        "sort": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "sort"
        }
    }
}
...
```